# portal users cannot own partner accounts

Tags: community

I am having an issue while updating an existing community contact/account: 
Contact has 'created by' and 'Owner' set to  Salesforce Standard User. And then from that Contact I created a community user.
Now with REST API I am trying to update that Contact's 'owner' field to Community user I see following error:
Portal users cannot own partner accounts

Answer (score 9):

This error message is confusing.  Basically, the system will prevent portal users from owning contacts that are linked to any kind of account, according to this knowledge article:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004491&language=en_US&type=1

> When you try to enable an Account as a Partner Account and any of the
>   contacts associated to that account are owned by a Partner User, you
>   would receive this error message. If Partner Account enabling was
>   allowed to go through successfully in such a scenario, it could result
>   in Partner Users owning Partner Contacts which is not allowed by
>   design.
>
> The only way to enable the Account as a Partner Account, when this
>   situation is encountered, is to update the ownership of the associated
>   Contacts so that they are owned by internal, non-Partner Users.

The only way for you to avoid the error is to use a beforeInsert trigger to change the contact ownership to an internal Salesforce license user.

Comment: Thanks David.. yeah I  looked at couple of documentation links.. make sense..